# i want to control two drop down lists to tell which macro to be run automatically

Tags: excel, vba

Currently i have this code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = True ' <-- just for tests
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1")) Is Nothing Then
  Select Case Target.Value  
   Case "Expander 1 eff"     
      CopyIncreaseRecord      
      Case "Expander 2 eff"  
     CopyIncreaseRecord       
      Case "Pump eff"  
       CopyIncreaseRecord     
      Case "Net Power"  
      CopyIncreaseRecordNetPower      
   End Select 
End If

End Sub
```

under the Sheet5 (Graph1)   view code.

presently i'm using one drop down in cell C1 to tell which macro to run automatically when i select an option in cell C1,

now i want to have two drop downs in cell C1 & in cell C2,
for example if C1 is selected "Expander 2 eff" and C2 is selected "Cycle eff" i want macro Expander2effvsCycleeff to run
if C1 is selected "Expander 2 eff" and C2 is selected "Massflowrate" i want macro Expander2effvsMassflowrate to run.

pls help, thanks in advance

i tried AI but it is not giving me the selection in two cells to be met

Comment: First somehow you have to define when the two dropdowns contain the really valid data. E.g. add a command_button to click if data are correct

Comment: Which of those procedures (macros) write to sheet `Sheet5`? If `C2` is neither of the 2 values, do nothing or `CopyIncreaseRecord`?

Answer (score 1):

### A Worksheet Change: Call Procedures Dependent on Drop-Down Selections

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Me.Range("C1,C2"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim Str1 As String: Str1 = LCase(CStr(Me.Range("C1").Value))
    Dim Str2 As String: Str2 = LCase(CStr(Me.Range("C2").Value))
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Select Case Str1
        Case "expander 1 eff", "pump eff", "net power"
            CopyIncreaseRecord
        Case "expander 2 eff"
            Select Case Str2
                Case "cycle eff": Expander2effvsCycleeff
                Case "massflowrate": Expander2effvsMassflowrate
                Case Else: ' CopyIncreaseRecord ' ???
            End Select
        Case Else: ' do nothing ???
    End Select

ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, but I already got it done and my code isn't this complicated, may be your code will make things simple in the long run. I'll keep it in record. It helps me learn more. I'll also give you a vote up

Comment: @JagadeshraoThalur then please post an answer with your solution

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E1, E2")) Is Nothing Then
Dim selectedValueE1 As String
Dim selectedValueE2 As String

```
    ' Clear columns A and B
    Range("A:B").ClearContents
    
    ' Get the selected values from cells E1 and E2
    selectedValueE1 = Range("E1").Value
    selectedValueE2 = Range("E2").Value
    
    ' Check the combined selections and run the appropriate macro
    Select Case selectedValueE1 & "|" & selectedValueE2
        Case "Expander 1 eff|Cycle eff"
            CopyIncreaseRecord
        Case "Expander 2 eff|Cycle eff"
            CopyIncreaseRecord
        Case "Pump eff|Cycle eff"
            CopyIncreaseRecord
```

'           Case "Net Power|Cycle eff"
'              CopyIncreaseRecordNetPower
Case "AirInTemp|Cycle eff"
CopyIncreaseRecordAirInTemp
Case "CO2PumpOutPressure|Cycle eff"
CopyIncreaseRecordCO2PumpOutPressure

```
        Case "Expander 1 eff|Massflowrate"
            CopyIncreaseRecord
        Case "Expander 2 eff|Massflowrate"
            CopyIncreaseRecord
        Case "Pump eff|Massflowrate"
            CopyIncreaseRecord
```

'         Case "Net Power|Massflowrate"
'            CopyIncreaseRecordNetPower
Case "AirInTemp|Massflowrate"
CopyIncreaseRecordAirInTemp
Case "CO2PumpOutPressure|Massflowrate"
CopyIncreaseRecordCO2PumpOutPressure
' Add more cases for other combinations as needed
' ...
End Select
End If
End Sub